# Referencing color value in layout attributes

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have two layouts defined. I want to have different font colors for both of them. White font for dark layout, black for light.
So I defined color as:

```
<android:textColor="?attr/myColor">
```

in attributes:

```
<attr name="myColor" format="color|reference"/>
```

and for both themes:
for light:

```
<item name="myColor">#000000</item>
```

and dark

```
<item name="myColor">#FFFFFF</item>
```

but it is not working. App crashes and I receive error:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a ColorStateList (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f01000d a=-1}
```

Any ideas? Is there another possibility to get it done?

Comment: check that http://stackoverflow.com/a/31653169/2401265

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android text styling error - Resource is not a ColorStateList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653078/android-text-styling-error-resource-is-not-a-colorstatelist)