# Android ‘InvocationTargetException‘ and 'UnsupportedOperationException'

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-xml

I have encountered a problem on OPPO X905 and OPPO X907， both are of Android 4.0.3(API Level 15), I haven't used any higher level API, and I have searched on Google and SO, all are different from my problem, below are my xml file and crash log, thanks in advance.

xml file:(the margin of divider was originally 7.5dp, could this be the problem?)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_full"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#eff0f7"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_first_half"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <View
            android:id="@+id/first_path"
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_car_action_path" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im_car_direction_icon"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_car_action_background"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/selector_navi_icon_63" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/second_path"
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/im_car_direction_icon"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_car_action_path" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_direction"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="68dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@drawable/selector_car_route_turn_text"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_second_half"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp" >
        <View
            android:id="@+id/third_path"
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_car_action_path" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_road_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="68dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@drawable/selector_car_route_desc"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/divider_for_road_and_distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv_road_name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_road_name"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="|"
            android:textColor="@drawable/selector_car_route_desc"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_ride_distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/divider_for_road_and_distance"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/divider_for_road_and_distance"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@drawable/selector_car_route_desc"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="68dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
            android:background="#dee1f0" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The drawable/selector_car_route_desc file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/color_999999"/>
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:color="@color/color_333333"/>

</selector>
```

crash log:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #106: Error inflating class <unknown>
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
com.tencent.map.ama.route.ui.view.e.<init>(CarRouteShowItem.java:78)
com.tencent.map.ama.route.ui.view.f.a(CarRouteShowView.java:100)
com.tencent.map.ama.route.ui.view.d.a(CarRouteDetailView.java:37)
com.tencent.map.ama.route.ui.MapStateCarRoute.e(MapStateCarRoute.java:418)
com.tencent.map.ama.route.ui.MapStateCarRoute$1.run(MapStateCarRoute.java:255)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4476)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:808)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:575)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
cause by:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
com.tencent.map.ama.route.ui.view.e.<init>(CarRouteShowItem.java:78)
com.tencent.map.ama.route.ui.view.f.a(CarRouteShowView.java:100)
com.tencent.map.ama.route.ui.view.d.a(CarRouteDetailView.java:37)
com.tencent.map.ama.route.ui.MapStateCarRoute.e(MapStateCarRoute.java:418)
com.tencent.map.ama.route.ui.MapStateCarRoute$1.run(MapStateCarRoute.java:255)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4476)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:808)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:575)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
cause by:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x12
android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:463)
android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2849)
android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:499)
android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:492)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
com.tencent.map.ama.route.ui.view.e.<init>(CarRouteShowItem.java:78)
com.tencent.map.ama.route.ui.view.f.a(CarRouteShowView.java:100)
com.tencent.map.ama.route.ui.view.d.a(CarRouteDetailView.java:37)
com.tencent.map.ama.route.ui.MapStateCarRoute.e(MapStateCarRoute.java:418)
com.tencent.map.ama.route.ui.MapStateCarRoute$1.run(MapStateCarRoute.java:255)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4476)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:808)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:575)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the code of CarRouteShowItem.java:78 is like this:

```
View mView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.car_route_detail_item, null);
```

The CarRouteShowItem is not child of View, its code is as follows:

```
public class CarRouteShowItem {

    private Context mContext;

    private View mView;

    public CarRouteShowItem(Context context) {
        mContext = context;

        // mView is used by caller 
        mView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.car_route_detail_item, null);

        // some view finds 
    }

        // some other methods related with specific logic
}
```

The graphic layout could preview in the Eclipse from API level 8 to API level 23, but when I preview it in Android Studio on API level 15, it gives the error message:**Couldn't resolve resource @style/Widget.TextView**, other API levels are OK, but I haven't use the style for TextView.

Comment: try something like -  LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, viewGroup, false);
 
Here context is not your context but that of the overriden method

Comment: @KaveeshKanwal What do you mean by the overriden method, and my class is not a view, which ViewGroup shold I pass to the LayoutInflate.

Comment: can u show ur CarRouteShowItem.java

Comment: @KaveeshKanwal I have added the core code of the class in the question.

Comment: Does it get rendered inside the layout preview window in the IDE?

Comment: @DanielMendel I have add the preview result in the question, could you tell me the problem.

Answer (score 4):

*All you need is an extra eye* :-)

[image]

```
 android:layout_height="1px"
```

hope you can see now. The last child in your second `RelativeLayout` with id `item_second_half` of type `<View` change it to

```
android:layout_height="1dp"
```

*let me have my eye back as soon as possible*

Comment: I don't think this was the reason, because that the simple list divider's height is 1px, and my crash was reported at the TextView.

Comment: really?? did you try it,Sir? well try it! - who said textview? line 106 Sir, is the error@twlkyao

Comment: The crash log said that, and at other place, we all set listview's divider height is 1px

Comment: all i want to know is did you try it??@twlkyao because from what i see the error is that. so did you?

Comment: actually if you see here(http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence) you will see that isn't best practise to use hard coded pixels, not error. So your suggestion isn't the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is somewhere in @style/ referenced in AppTheme. Try to remove all of them (reset to default) and add one-by-one until the crash occurs. This way you can find the style that has wrong attributes.

if you see down on your log error you will see that the InvocationTargetException occurs by java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x12

UPDATE

I noticed something bad in your xml file, you are using text color as "drawable", you have to use colors xml file ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31653169/2401265))

**UPDATE AGAIN**

after more search i found this [file](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView) if you see the 499 and 492 line (that appears on logerror) you will see that maybe it couldn't find style for textview

Comment: text color as "drawable" is ok. It is color state list resource (http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html)

Comment: yes it has to be color not drawable, check the first example from your link

Comment: @gmetax will this cause the crash, it is not certain appear, but before the project has somewhere define color in drawable folder.

Comment: ok maybe the color isn't the problem, but it is sure that the problem is in textview. have you tested to remove all the apptheme references?

Comment: because i see that in logcat "android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:463)..." it's trying to load some dimens from the theme and crashes

Comment: Yeah, I use Android Studio find it gives me some error message(updated in the question), but I couldn't find the style anywhere, why it tries to load that from theme?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90524/discussion-between-gmetax-and-twlkyao).